# Python - execute sequential commands in same windows command prompt

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to Python (been learning for a few days) . Can anyone help me with the following issue please?

I am trying to write a program to automate the testing of built in commands of a product which is installed on windows and linux.

Before any of the commands can run, the profile needs to be set using profile.cmd.

The commands ( command1.cmd, command2.cmd etc) then need to run in the same  windows command prompt as profile.cmd as they rely on the environment which this sets.

The problem I find is that after profile.cmd has been run, python closes the windows command prompt and opens a new one for command1.cmd.

command1.cmd therefore fails to run properly as it is in a new command prompt which has not had the environment set by profile.cmd.

My code is shown below.  I am currently testing on windows but will also need to test on linux.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks - Kevin

```
import subprocess
rc = subprocess.run (["profile.cmd"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(rc.stdout.decode("ascii"))

rc = subprocess.run (["command1.cmd"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(rc.stdout.decode("ascii"))

rc = subprocess.run (["command2.cmd"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(rc.stdout.decode("ascii"))

rc = subprocess.run (["command3.cmd"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(rc.stdout.decode("ascii"))
```